# rails ancestry get the all last children by the root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ancestry

i have this record in Folder class

```
Folder 1 = parent id: root
  sub folder 1 = parent id: Folder 1
    secret file1 = parent id: Folder 1/sub folder 1
      my folder1 = parent id: Folder 1/ sub folder 1/ secret file1

Folder 2
 sub folder 2 = parent id: Folder 2
  secret file2 = parent id: Folder 2/sub folder 2
   my folder2 = parent id: Folder 2/ sub folder 2/ secret file2
```

now i have this in my html

```
- folder.indirects.each do |sub|
   div.col
    div.form-group
     = sub.name
```

and im getting like this

> secret file1
>
> my folder1
>
> secret file2
>
> my folder2

but my goal is to get the "my folder1" and "my folder2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you basically want to get all leaf nodes, right?

You can do it by iterating through all descendants and rejecting nodes with children. It might not be the most performant solution but it will work.

```rb
 - folder.descendants.reject(&:has_children?).each do |sub|
   div.col
    div.form-group
     = sub.name
```

BTW using the `indirects` method is wrong for trees with [level](http://typeocaml.com/2014/11/26/height-depth-and-level-of-a-tree/) = 2, because in this case you'd be rejecting root's direct children, which are also leafs in this case.

Comment: i dont know why my answer deleted by some one but i already solve this

Comment: ill accept your code is more clean and working thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
- folder.indirects.each do |sub|
  - if sub.children.blank?
    div.col
      div.form-group
       = sub.name
```

i use if so i can rid the other folder